# CSS Grid: can I specify margin for each row of a grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Lets say I have a grid of elements like this, this is simple CSS grid

[image: Lets say I have]

Any way I can set margin for the second row of this grid like this?
I've tried to control elements via nth-child, but it messed up first row.

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin: 0 -18px 10px;
  gap: 14px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 13px 0;
}

.item {
display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 146px;
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 27px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #082b26;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;}
```

```html
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class='item'>1</div>
            <div class='item'>2</div>
            <div class='item'>3</div>
            <div class='item'>4</div>
            <div class='item'>5</div>
            <div class='item'>6</div>
          </div>
```

Comment: There's almost certainly a way of doing what you require (even if it's with an entirely different solution than you expect); but if you don't show representative code then we can't really help without making guesses, which is of little use to you *or* future visitors to the site and this question. Please: share the "*[mcve]*" code required to reproduce your problem/situation.

Comment: you could reset the number and sizes of columns and have the chid span them ... or use position:relative + left or translate() or negative margins or any other method you could think about. We are missing your HTML and CSS that reproduces your screenshot and issu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only possible if you know the exact amount of columns. Then you can target the elements of the 2nd row with `nth-child` and add a margin to them to offset them from their normal placement.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(n+4):not(:nth-child(n+7)) {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: -50px;
}



/* for vizualisation only */
.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```